# randomly filling in empty spaces in a matrix - O(N) amortized time?

Tags: algorithms, performance, big-o

Here are two ways to answer the following question. I'm trying to confirm what I believe their time complexity to be:

*If I had a snake game with a x,y matrix of spaces, some of which were occupied the snake, how would I best find an available space to place an apple?*

1. I could run through the existing matrix and store a new list of coords which are free, then pick a random element from that array.
2. I could pick a random x,y and, if it's taken, pick another random coord (repeating as necessary)

It seems like the first one is O(N) time, since it always checks each space in the playfield once

The second one seems like O(N) amortized, since if the snake is at 50% of the playfield then on average it will take N checks to find an open space. Yet if the snake is smaller than 50%, the random approach will be better, and if it's more than 50%, it will be worse.

Is this thinking correct? I'm not sure I'm using the term "amortized" correctly, since I have only had a very brief introduction to the concept in the context of dynamic arrays in ruby.

Comment: You can also get an `O(snake)` solution by taking a random integer from `[0, N-snake[` and then test each element of the snake whether it's smaller than  your integer and needs to be skipped when translating the integer to a position.

Comment: The second one should be O(n log(n)) if you completely fill the matrix. If you only fill it up to a fixed fraction independent of n, it's only O(n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this thinking correct?

Mostly, but no exactly: If the snake is 50%, each try has 50% of getting a free space. So the probability is:

- 50% of getting a position in O(1*k)
- 75% of getting a position in O(2*k) or less
- 87.5% of getting a position in O(3*k) or less
- 99.9% of getting a position in O(10*k) or less

Considering this, you would be much better of trying a simple random than a linear search. However, in games, predictability is some times better than speed. You could also make some hybride: try randomly 5 times and then goes linear, so 5 random tries have not a big impact and the linear solution solve in a predictable time the worse cases.

If your matrix is all occupied by the snake but 1 cell, then the linear search is better.

**Others alternatives:**

Let define your grid of WxH, where each cell is at w x h (note: upper / lower case).

We may define a hash to identify each cell as: w*H+h;

If you create a hash table of references to empty cells, inserting/removing/reading the table is O(k).

Every time you move your snake, you update the table, so it keep always the empty cells.

You could generate a random number in [0,W*H), use this value as hash value and access the table for getting a position for your apple. That stay at O(k).

Comment: I don't get how your alternative is any different from the second approach - the generated random number from [0, W*H] might as well point to a snake field not an empty one.

Comment: @Bergi I think I see what Adrian is getting at. If you store a separate list of _available_ spaces that is updated whenever the snake moves, you no longer have to iterate through each space when it comes time to place a new apple. Then when you pick a random W,H you know that it will be available and there is no risk of snake collision.

Comment: Correct, but it needs to be a hash-table (unordered_map in C++), because if not, searching/inserting/deleting from the container would counter any benefit of using this way: A linked list has linear access, arrays has linear removal.

Comment: What is the k in 2*k ?

Comment: @Paparazzi: K is a constant time, in this case, the time to test if a single cell is or not empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your first approach like this:

1. Determine how many acceptable fields there are:
   #acceptable = #fields - #all_snake_parts - #walls - #whatever.
   This might be cached or easily calculated from available data in O(1).
2. Select a number from (0, #acceptable] and find that free field in O(#fields).

The changed approach uses O(1) space and O(#fields) time, instead of O(#free) space and O(#fields) time.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only 1 cell open the random is going to be worse as it will create some duplicates.  It will take more than n random to get n unique.

If you have just 2 or more cells open then random is better and will find is just over n / 2 tries.  It is pretty close to n / open cell.

The problem is if there are no open cells a random approach never finishes.

You could go with a couple approaches

1. stop at like n / 5 and then go to scan the array
2. store the guesses in a hashset and when the hashset size is the size of the array you stop

test program

```
private static double FindOpen()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int runs = 100;
    int sample = 100;
    int guesses = 0;
    double answer = 0;
    HashSet<int> full = new HashSet<int>();
    HashSet<int> findme = new HashSet<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sample; i++)
    {
        while (!findme.Add(rand.Next(sample))) { };
        //if (findme.Count < sample * 2 / 10)
        //    continue;
        guesses = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < sample * runs; j++)
        {
            full.Clear();
            int r = rand.Next(sample);
            full.Add(r);
            guesses++;                 
            while (!findme.Contains(r))
            {
                if (full.Count == sample)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("full.Count == sample");
                }
                guesses++;
                r = rand.Next(sample);
                full.Add(r);                      
            }
        }
        double avgGuesses = (double)guesses / runs / sample ;
        double fraction = avgGuesses / sample;
        Debug.WriteLine($"empty = {i + 1}/{sample}  average gusses = {avgGuesses.ToString("N2")}   avgGuesses/{sample} = {fraction.ToString("N4")}");
    }
    return (answer);
}
```

empty = 1/100  average gusses = 100.41  avgGuesses/100 = 1.0041
    empty = 2/100  average gusses = 50.24   avgGuesses/100 = 0.5024
    empty = 3/100  average gusses = 34.04   avgGuesses/100 = 0.3404
    empty = 4/100  average gusses = 25.13   avgGuesses/100 = 0.2513
    empty = 5/100  average gusses = 19.90   avgGuesses/100 = 0.1990
    empty = 6/100  average gusses = 16.60   avgGuesses/100 = 0.1660
    empty = 7/100  average gusses = 14.02   avgGuesses/100 = 0.1402
    empty = 8/100  average gusses = 12.60   avgGuesses/100 = 0.1260
    empty = 9/100  average gusses = 11.04   avgGuesses/100 = 0.1104
    empty = 10/100  average gusses = 10.10   avgGuesses/100 = 0.1010
    empty = 11/100  average gusses = 9.13   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0913
    empty = 12/100  average gusses = 8.31   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0831
    empty = 13/100  average gusses = 7.67   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0767
    empty = 14/100  average gusses = 7.25   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0725
    empty = 15/100  average gusses = 6.71   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0671
    empty = 16/100  average gusses = 6.17   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0617
    empty = 17/100  average gusses = 5.91   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0591
    empty = 18/100  average gusses = 5.50   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0550
    empty = 19/100  average gusses = 5.23   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0523
    empty = 20/100  average gusses = 4.99   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0499
    empty = 21/100  average gusses = 4.71   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0471
    empty = 22/100  average gusses = 4.52   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0452
    empty = 23/100  average gusses = 4.36   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0436
    empty = 24/100  average gusses = 4.19   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0419
    empty = 25/100  average gusses = 4.05   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0405
    empty = 26/100  average gusses = 3.82   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0382
    empty = 27/100  average gusses = 3.72   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0372
    empty = 28/100  average gusses = 3.56   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0356
    empty = 29/100  average gusses = 3.43   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0343
    empty = 30/100  average gusses = 3.35   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0335
    empty = 31/100  average gusses = 3.23   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0323
    empty = 32/100  average gusses = 3.13   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0313
    empty = 33/100  average gusses = 3.03   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0303
    empty = 34/100  average gusses = 2.93   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0293
    empty = 35/100  average gusses = 2.83   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0283
    empty = 36/100  average gusses = 2.80   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0280
    empty = 37/100  average gusses = 2.71   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0271
    empty = 38/100  average gusses = 2.63   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0263
    empty = 39/100  average gusses = 2.58   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0258
    empty = 40/100  average gusses = 2.47   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0247
    empty = 41/100  average gusses = 2.41   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0241
    empty = 42/100  average gusses = 2.37   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0237
    empty = 43/100  average gusses = 2.33   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0233
    empty = 44/100  average gusses = 2.28   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0228
    empty = 45/100  average gusses = 2.22   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0222
    empty = 46/100  average gusses = 2.18   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0218
    empty = 47/100  average gusses = 2.15   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0215
    empty = 48/100  average gusses = 2.07   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0207
    empty = 49/100  average gusses = 2.05   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0205
    empty = 50/100  average gusses = 2.02   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0202
    empty = 51/100  average gusses = 1.94   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0194
    empty = 52/100  average gusses = 1.95   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0195
    empty = 53/100  average gusses = 1.90   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0190
    empty = 54/100  average gusses = 1.83   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0183
    empty = 55/100  average gusses = 1.83   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0183
    empty = 56/100  average gusses = 1.79   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0179
    empty = 57/100  average gusses = 1.75   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0175
    empty = 58/100  average gusses = 1.72   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0172
    empty = 59/100  average gusses = 1.68   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0168
    empty = 60/100  average gusses = 1.67   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0167
    empty = 61/100  average gusses = 1.64   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0164
    empty = 62/100  average gusses = 1.61   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0161
    empty = 63/100  average gusses = 1.60   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0160
    empty = 64/100  average gusses = 1.56   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0156
    empty = 65/100  average gusses = 1.53   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0153
    empty = 66/100  average gusses = 1.53   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0153
    empty = 67/100  average gusses = 1.49   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0149
    empty = 68/100  average gusses = 1.46   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0146
    empty = 69/100  average gusses = 1.45   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0145
    empty = 70/100  average gusses = 1.43   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0143
    empty = 71/100  average gusses = 1.41   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0141
    empty = 72/100  average gusses = 1.39   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0139
    empty = 73/100  average gusses = 1.36   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0136
    empty = 74/100  average gusses = 1.34   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0134
    empty = 75/100  average gusses = 1.32   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0132
    empty = 76/100  average gusses = 1.31   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0131
    empty = 77/100  average gusses = 1.30   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0130
    empty = 78/100  average gusses = 1.28   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0128
    empty = 79/100  average gusses = 1.27   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0127
    empty = 80/100  average gusses = 1.26   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0126
    empty = 81/100  average gusses = 1.24   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0124
    empty = 82/100  average gusses = 1.22   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0122
    empty = 83/100  average gusses = 1.21   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0121
    empty = 84/100  average gusses = 1.19   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0119
    empty = 85/100  average gusses = 1.18   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0118
    empty = 86/100  average gusses = 1.16   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0116
    empty = 87/100  average gusses = 1.14   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0114
    empty = 88/100  average gusses = 1.14   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0114
    empty = 89/100  average gusses = 1.12   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0112
    empty = 90/100  average gusses = 1.11   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0111
    empty = 91/100  average gusses = 1.10   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0110
    empty = 92/100  average gusses = 1.09   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0109
    empty = 93/100  average gusses = 1.08   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0108
    empty = 94/100  average gusses = 1.06   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0106
    empty = 95/100  average gusses = 1.05   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0105
    empty = 96/100  average gusses = 1.05   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0105
    empty = 97/100  average gusses = 1.03   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0103
    empty = 98/100  average gusses = 1.02   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0102
    empty = 99/100  average gusses = 1.01   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0101
    empty = 100/100  average gusses = 1.00   avgGuesses/100 = 0.0100

I am surprised one open cell did so well.  I would expect about 5 n due to duplicates.  At 1/2 it is around 2 which is what you should expect.